How does client identify the Destination connection ID from QUIC short header packets?
QUIC short header packets only contain the destination connection ID and not the length of the destination connection ID. How can a QUIC client retrieve the connection ID without the length required to identify the connection?
Further, the connection ID can be of variable sizes, and the same connection can have multiple connection IDs. So, length is required to identify the connection ID.
Also, QUIC doesn't restrict that one UDP connection to use one QUIC connection. Hence, multiple QUIC connections can go through one UDP connection.
What if the two connections have the same prefix for the connection IDs? I guess just checking the connection ID match doesn't work.
I tried reading RFCs and other blogs but couldn't get clarity. Please let me know how do clients deterministically determine the connection ID from short header packets.

QUIC short header packets can and will only be accepted after the handshake is completed (only long header packets are used during the handshake). After the handshake is completed, the connection ID length is known and this is used by the endpoint to parse short header packets.
With respect to multiple connection ID's: note that short header packets only contain the destination connection ID and that this connection ID is generated by the peer that receives the packets. So, if a peer (whether client or server) would use different connection ID lengths, it would know what to expect and anticipate. For example, it could somehow encode the length in the first part of the connection ID.
Although the specification allows this, I've never seen this being used. Even if a peer would (need to) use different lengths for different connections (for example for runtime migration to a longer connection ID), it could still use a fixed length for (new connection ID's for) an already established connection.
From https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9000.html#name-connection-id: "Packets with short headers (Section 17.3) only include the Destination Connection ID and omit the explicit length. The length of the Destination Connection ID field is expected to be known to endpoints. "
